# Use of と in this line

Tags: words, abbreviations

Short question.

Line from 愛は取り戻せ song:

> 俺との愛を守る為 お前は旅立ち

That と is just an abbreviation from 俺たち? Or is some grammatical point with の related? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anime lyrics translation says "In order to protect -our- love", from I guessed that it could be an abbreviation. That post seems to give a formal solution but this song is really, really informal. If this との would be a mere formal の, then it would say "In order to protect my love" (kinda weird).

Comment: The object of 守る is "(your) love with/toward me" → "our love". In general, Aとの愛 is "love between someone and A".